# How can I have cd show the directory it switches into?

Tags: bash, shell, cd-command

I have made my command prompt (`$PS1`) to be just username.../current_directory (using the 3 dots because my directory structure has lots of levels and they were taking up too much of the command line prompt).
However this would work better if, when I cd'd into a directory, the cd command showed what directory I get changed into.  How can I have this happen?

btw my command prompt setting (that I don't wish to change) to do username...current_dir is:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u.../${PWD##*/}\$ '
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With zsh

```
chpwd() pwd
```

Then, the current directory is printed whenever it changes (upon `cd`, `pushd`, `popd`...).

With ksh, bash or zsh:

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "$@" && pwd
}
```

(you'd typically put those in your shell configuration file)

Comment: Another tip you may want to add: in `bash`, setting `CDPATH=.` is another method to achieve what the OP wants.

Comment: @jw013, nice trick about CDPATH, however that doesn't output the path for `cd /absolute/path` (which is probably what the OP wants) or `cd ./foo` or `cd ..` or `cd ../bar`

Comment: That is true.  It is enough to cover 99% of the cases for me.  I rarely need to see the full path if I am already using an absolute path argument to `cd`, and when I use `./` or `..` I generally already know where I am.

Comment: Accepted, works great (bash).